# How to set up search with will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, will-paginate

I had install `will_paginate` and in the posts_controller index def write:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'id DESC', :conditions => ['title like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

But search doesn't work. When I click on search button it changes url to:

```
http://178.62.xxx.xxx/find/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=the
```

And the posts in the page stay the same.

Routes:

```
get "/find/" => "posts#index"
```

Post model:

```
def self.search(query)
where("title like :title", title: "%#{query.strip.chomp}%")
```

end

In the index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag('/find/', :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Найти посты", :class => "search" %>
      <%= submit_tag "OK", :name => nil, :class => "search_btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### I solved it.

First, I created search form which request to index action (`GET /posts`).

```
# index.html.erb - Search Form
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, "" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Next, I defined index action.

```
# Controller
def index
  # params = { :search => 'search keywords ...' }
  @products = Product.search(params).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end
```

Then, define `Post#search`.

`paginate` method is used on only `ActiveRecord::Relation`.
So, `Post#search` must return `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

```
def self.search(params)
  products = all # for not existing params args
  products = products.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search]
  products
end
```

That's all.

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error here

Comment: Worked beautifully for me, except that 'all' returned Array instead of Relation. Used Products.order('name') instead.

Comment: This is MAJESTICALLY simple.  Thank you.